# Split string start and end character

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

For example, I have this string :

```
string myString="abc {string 1} def {string 2}{string 3}";
```

I need to get an array of strings with :

```
string 1
string 2
string 3
```

or

```
{string 1}
{string 2}
{string 3}
```

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: you could try it with `regex`

Comment: A simple regex would work. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Regex would probably be better than splitting

Comment: `regex101.com` will help you to learn regular expression and build expression for your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex. This is the search you would want to preform:

```
{.+?}
```

For example:

```
    string input = "abc {string 1} def {string 2}{string 3}";
    string pattern = "{.+?}";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
    if (matches.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1} matches):", input, matches.Count);
        foreach (Match match in matches)
            Console.WriteLine("   " + match.Value);
    }
```

yields

```
abc {string 1} def {string 2}{string 3} (3 matches):
   {string 1}
   {string 2}
   {string 3}
```

Comment: All those capturing groups are not needed, just use `{.+?}`  or `(?<={).+?(?=})` to not include the curly braces in the match.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, your suggestion is an improvement

Answer (score 0):

Here is a LINQ solution:

```
string myString="abc {string 1} def {string 2}{string 3}";

string[] result = myString.Split('{')
                          .Where(x => x.Contains("}"))
                          .Select(x => new string(x.TakeWhile(c => c != '}').ToArray()))
                          .ToArray();
```

**result:**

```
result[0]="string 1"

result[1]="string 2"

result[2]="string 3"
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/n3I5kX)